# BLDC motor is locking method to reduce the phase current

Tags: stm32, brushless-dc-motor

I'm using the BLDC motor rotating as a six-step commutation method. Now, I want to add the Anti-Theft method feature to lock the motor's rotation on both sides to change the wrong six-step commutation method. It worked, But the phase current flow is more than 20 Amps. How can I reduce the phase current in this method?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.